# JavaScript causes error on nodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a nodeJS test script with socket.io but the deployed script on my server causes an error if I am trying to include any javascript.

Just calling the HTML via nginx on my localhost does not throw any error.

this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>NodeJS Realtime Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Moin!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the content of the app.js:

```
console.log("test");
```

Chrome throws me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1
```

In Opera, the error is:

```
Syntax error at line 1 while loading: expected expression, got '<'  Linked script compilation   app.js
```

also, the debugger shows that the error occurs on char one of my index.html file.
what am I missing here?

Comment: The error in Chrome is pointing to line 1 in _app.js_, not in index.html. Did you look what the file `/client/app.js` looks like by opening it in the browser (or using Chrome's dev tools)?

Comment: indeed. opening app.js on the server shows the content of index.html. so it is the server configuration that is causing the error. I took the one from the socket.io example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Jani Hartikainen I recognized that it was a misconfiguration of the nodeJS server.

The example I used served index.html on any request on the server.
It works using this configuration: https://gist.github.com/701407